# Create a dynamic WHERE clause with LINQ to SharePoint

Tags: 2013, caml, linq

I have a custom application where the user can select multiple (13) parameters to select data from a SharePoint list. To achieve this, I want to use LINQ to query this data from SharePoint.

The enduser can select from different dropdowns to filter. I need to build a dynamic query for these "filters".

I know how to achieve this by CAML but due to the large amount of filters, its highly complicated to build a CAML with possible 13 AND's.

I want to use LINQ to SharePoint but you are not able to create dynamic WHERE clauses.

Is it possible to create dynamic WHERE clauses and if yes how?

Comment: It is possible to build dynamic using CAML. never used LINQ. If want CAML, I can help

Comment: @Gauras. Ok, thanks a lot! You have 13 possible <eq>'s due to selected filters. But when the users selects only 2 filters, then you will have 2 EQs. If the users selects all 13 filters, then you will have 13 EQs. My problem is to create out of these n to 13 filter a dynamic CAML all linked with ANDs. Could you show me a way to build such a dynamic CAML query with n EQs?

Comment: Use Camlex to build dynamic query: https://camlex.codeplex.com/

Comment: ok, can you tell me how you storing the user selected data? So I can create a sample code and share with you. Also Which type of columns are all those? All Choice column or anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Thanks to Pawel: https://buli.waw.pl/caml-query-multiple-conditions-in-and-or-clause/

He has provided a small codesnippet for dynamic CAML building which works fine.

```
enum MergeType { Or, And };

/// <summary>
/// Merge CAML conditions in code
/// </summary>
/// <param name="conditions">A list of contitions to merge into alternative or conjunction</param>
/// <param name="type"><value>MergeType.Or</value> for alternative, MergeType.And for conjunction</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static string MergeCAMLConditions(List<string> conditions, MergeType type)
{
    // No conditions => empty response
    if (conditions.Count == 0) return "";

    // Initialize temporary variables
    string typeStart = (type == MergeType.And ? "<And>" : "<Or>");
    string typeEnd = (type == MergeType.And ? "</And>" : "</Or>");

    // Build hierarchical structure
    while (conditions.Count >= 2)
    {
        List<string> complexConditions = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < conditions.Count; i+=2)
        {
            if (conditions.Count == i + 1) // Only one condition left
                complexConditions.Add(conditions[i]);
            else // Two condotions - merge
                complexConditions.Add(typeStart + conditions[i] + conditions[i + 1] + typeEnd);
        }

        conditions = complexConditions;
    }

    return conditions[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that **field1Value** is the 1st filter control's value which is available on your form as so on. Use the second *if* block *n* number of times as you want. (12 in your case)

```
bool indicator = false;
string query = String.Empty;

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(field1Value))
query +="<Eq><FieldRef Name='columnName1'/><Value Type='columnType'>field1Value</Value></Eq>"

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(field2Value)){
  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query)){    
     indicator = true;
   }
query +="<Eq><FieldRef Name='columnName2'/><Value Type='columnType'>field2Value</Value></Eq>"
   if(indicator){
     query = "<And>" + query + "</And>";
     indicator = false;
   }  
}


if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(field3Value)){
  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query)){    
     indicator = true;
   }
query +="<Eq><FieldRef Name='columnName3'/><Value Type='columnType'>field3Value</Value></Eq>"
   if(indicator){
     query = "<And>" + query + "</And>";
     indicator = false;
   }  
}

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(field4Value)){
  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query)){    
     indicator = true;
   }
query +="<Eq><FieldRef Name='columnName4'/><Value Type='columnType'>field4Value</Value></Eq>"
   if(indicator){
     query = "<And>" + query + "</And>";
     indicator = false;
   }  
}

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(field5Value)){
  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query)){    
     indicator = true;
   }
query +="<Eq><FieldRef Name='columnName5'/><Value Type='columnType'>field5Value</Value></Eq>"
   if(indicator){
     query = "<And>" + query + "</And>";
     indicator = false;
   }  
}
```

As final step you can do the following:

```
query = "<Where>"+query + "</Where>";
```

Mark it as answer if works for you. Someone might be looking for similar post, it would be beneficial for them too