# How would you write conditional Where / AND statements with SharePoint Dynamic LINQ?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, linq

Has anyone been able to solve this issue? I've scoured the Internet, and nobody seems to have the correct answer.

Found a similar question here, but everyone seems to give answers related to CAML: [Create a dynamic WHERE clause with LINQ to SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/161979/create-a-dynamic-where-clause-with-linq-to-sharepoint)

I'm already using Dynamic LINQ: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

I also use dynamic sorting on grid view headers, so Dynamic LINQ is necessary.

The problem is building a dynamic where clause with multiple conditional (meaning only add the clause if a drop-down selection is made) AND statements using LINQ.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee538250\(v=office.14\)) Unfortunately I am not sure whether it will still work in higher version of on-premise SharePoint i.e. 2016 or 2019 but you could try

Comment: There's nothing in this that addresses the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and forgot to post the answer for future reference.

Using Dynamic LINQ, you can conditionally add more clauses like the following function below.

I'm checking each drop-down selection and ensuring the where clause is empty before appending the additional clause.

Each time a selection is made from any of my drop-down lists, the function is called.

The dynamic LINQ query then repopulates the grid view.

```
void filterGrid()
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
        {
            PortalDataContext db = new PortalDataContext(@"SQLServer");

            if (ddlCerts.SelectedItem.Text == string.Empty && ddlCertType.SelectedItem.Text == string.Empty && ddlPrograms.SelectedItem.Text == string.Empty && ddlCustomers.SelectedValue == string.Empty)
            {
                var qryEmpSearch = from c in db.vw_EmployeeSearches
                                   orderby c.LastName
                                   select c;

                gvEmpSearch.DataSource = qryEmpSearch;

            }
            else
            {
                if (ddlCerts.SelectedValue != string.Empty)
                    strEmpSearchWhere = "cert_name == \"" + ddlCerts.SelectedValue + "\"";

                if (ddlPrograms.SelectedValue != string.Empty)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strEmpSearchWhere))
                        strEmpSearchWhere += " And ";
                    strEmpSearchWhere += "program_name == \"" + ddlPrograms.SelectedValue + "\"";
                }

                if (ddlCustomers.SelectedValue != string.Empty)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strEmpSearchWhere))
                        strEmpSearchWhere += " And ";
                    strEmpSearchWhere += "cust_name == \"" + ddlCustomers.SelectedValue + "\"";
                }

                if (ddlCertType.SelectedValue != string.Empty)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strEmpSearchWhere))
                        strEmpSearchWhere += " And ";
                    strEmpSearchWhere += "cert_type_name == \"" + ddlCertType.SelectedValue + "\"";
                }

                ViewState["strEmpSearchWhere"] = strEmpSearchWhere;

                var qryEmpSearch = from c in db.vw_EmployeeSearches.Where(strEmpSearchWhere)
                                   orderby c.LastName
                                   select c;

                gvEmpSearch.DataSource = qryEmpSearch;

            }

            gvEmpSearch.DataBind();

        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to the following article to use LINQ

https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-dynamically-add-where-clause-in-linq

Comment: None of these examples address the question/problem.